# Web Automation Python Robotframework & Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, robotframework

I have to build an automation framework using selenium, robot framework, and python. Which IDE shall I use VS Code or PyCharm, plugins required for IDEs?

I am using VS Code with plugins - Robot Framework Intellisense, Robot Framework Language Server, Autotypeing is not working. Need help from the group.

Test case is passing.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use RIDE? The commonly used editor for robotframework.

Reference:
https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-ride/